# How to get all Wikidata items in a country?

Tags: geospatial, wikidata, sparql

Using SPARQL I want to show all French embassies in Liberia (spoiler: there is exactly one)

So I wrote [this naive query](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fitem%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%09%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ3917681.%0A%20%20%09%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP137%20wd%3AQ142.%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP17%20wd%3AQ1014.%0A%7D):

```
SELECT ?item WHERE {
    ?item wdt:P17 wd:Q1014.    # country: Liberia
    ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q3917681. # instance of: embassy
    ?item wdt:P137 wd:Q142.    # operated by: France
}
```

**PROBLEM**: It finds **zero** items. Even though [there is such an item in Liberia](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q2841656), more exactly it is [located in the administrative territorial entity](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P131) of "[Monrovia](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q3748)", which itself has a [country](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P17) value of "[Liberia](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q1014)".

More generally, I want to get ALL Wikidata items that are in a particular country. How to do?

It must also work if you replace Q1014 (Liberia) with Q183 (Germany), which is even trickier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query does the trick:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?item WHERE {
    ?item wdt:P131*/wdt:P17 wd:Q1014.    # country: Liberia (recursive)
    ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q3917681.           # instance of: embassy
    ?item wdt:P137 wd:Q142.              # operated by: France
}
```

It includes all sub-regions of the country.
It does not show any duplicates.

Comment: Now it works with Q183.

Answer (score 3):

Not as straight forward as it seems.
Here's a first attempt which works for the Liberian example.

```
    SELECT ?item ?territory ?territoryLabel 
WHERE {
    ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q3917681. # instance of: embassy
    ?item wdt:P137 wd:Q142.    # operated by: France
    ?item wdt:P131 ?territory .
    ?territory wdt:P17 wd:Q1014 . #countries seem to have a wdt:P17 property of their id
      SERVICE wikibase:label {
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" .
}
  }
ORDER BY ?item
```

Gives duplicates for countries that have changed.
See [Minsk](http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q2841734) as an example of a territory in many former countries.
A generic query would need to filter these out.

Comment: Obviously, I would prefer a query that works for all such examples, and gives no duplicates :-) Is there maybe a way to remove duplicates within the query itself?

Comment: Also, would that work for a village located in a region located in a prefecture located in a country? The levels of "located in the administrative territorial entity" can be arbitrarily deep.